# Refreshing an android app activity

Tags: java, android, refresh

Is this A correct way to manually refresh an activity?

```
....
case R.id.action_refresh:
        Intent i = new Intent(Homepage.this, Homepage.class);
        Toast.makeText(Homepage.this, "refreshing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        startActivity(i);
```

seeing that this method destroys the activity and recreates it, i was wandering weither it may be to much of a costly method.

Comment: Can't you just update the content of the activity? I suggest you create an init() method on your activity to set the content and then call this method instead of doing all you need in the onCreate method

Comment: still if you want to refresh and recreate the activity use `recreate()` method...

Comment: The easiest way is to call onCreate(null); and your activity will be like new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method given by you is a standard one. But if you need another method you can use the following method

```
 onCreate(null)
```