# Refreshing an android app

Tags: java, android

Hi

How to refresh a android activity in native coding(java).

Comment: In my case, form submission, I just clear data manually

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refreshing an android app activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736610/refreshing-an-android-app-activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the stackoverflow because it has a similar question which i have answered. I am sending you the stackoverflow link to make your search easy.

[Refreshing an android app activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736610/refreshing-an-android-app-activity/21737213#21737213)

See even the question title is similar.

Comment: Sorry for the question , but that was helpful.